Borland C++Builder 5 & 6 compile from command line
I have recently been requested by my manager to hop on to an old client's software written in Borland C++Builder 5 and 6 (yes, extremely old, but rewriting and replacing these programs will cost millions, so maintenance is preferable).
I've been requested to check the option to implement a CI pipeline for these programs using Azure devops.
My question is, how can I compile both programs from CMD?
I've seen the following:

How do I build project files and packages for Borland C++ Builder 5 from the command line? This provided the most help (wimh answer), but it seems that I miss more flags and the make fails. (how can I know?)

Why can't the Borland C++ Builder 5 command line compiler find my files?

What is the difference between building C++ Builder project from IDE and command line?

and several others, but none helped.


I know that these two IDEs are EXTREMELY old, but this does not look like such a complicated task. Hence I require your help.
I also have a C++Builder 2009 project, where I have the option to see the command-line it uses to compile, and using that I was able to implement a CI for that particular program, but in C++Builder 5 and 6 I don't see that option.
Also, I've done several in-depth Google searches, and tried exploring the C++Builder 5 and 6 processes using Process Explorer, and consulting several employees in our company, but that did not help, unfortunately.
Edit 1:
this was done for both programs:  I tried multiple things:

as suggested by wimh, i tried using the make command directly on the .bpr (and bpg). the make command did not work for the bpg at all (not even an error message), and for the bpr it gave an error of an invalid make file. (this is true for both builder 5 and 6 respectively, using the make from each bin directory.
because of the invalid makefile, i used the bpr2mak to convert each program bpr to its respective .mak file, and than i retried the make again - now with different results: both programs "make" states that it cannot find some files, altough the "missing" files are exactly in the path it states (all files are local on disk) - I cant figure this one out - the files DO exist exactly where it looks...
Error E2194: Could not fine file  that are ALL exist. i checked manually.
It looks something like this - I cant rename\change directories. how can i handle the paths? or make it respect spaces? (what is this B.S lol)
maybe use python to edit the makefile and copy all required files to a different location?


If I recall correctly, if you right-click in the IDE's project manager, it'll pop up a menu with an option to export a makefile. It seems like I may vaguely recall hearing about somebody having trouble with what it produced, but I'm not sure--and it seems like it was pretty rare, even if I'm remembering the right thing.

What is the EXACT problem you are having with using the command line compilers in BCB 5&6? Please [edit] your question to include the commands you have tried, and explain why they are not working for you.

@RemyLebeau, please see Edit1. thanks
